# regular expression in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

in my application i have a text box in that '123456789v' first 9 charecter must be digits after that any character or a particular character how can i write please help me. thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last character must be a alphabet:

```
^[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]$
```

If the last character can be anything other than a number

```
^[0-9]{9}[^0-9]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like:
`[0-9]{9}.`

Or if the last character must be an alpha character:
`[0-9]{9}[a-z]`

If you are new to regular expression I sujest you get your hands on a tool to help you with them. I personaly like this Expresso: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm but you can also google for a "regex designer" as there a number of good ones online.

Comment: ok mr.Geoff it is workin but i need 9 digits and one character should any alphabet thank u for response

Answer (score 1):

How about: `\d{9}.`

Edit: Explained the regex:

```
\d = Any digit
{9} = 9 times
. = Any character
```

Comment: mr.Scoregraphic it is working when i type 1 to 9 digits after that i type a alphabet it is giving error message

Comment: Please provide some test input/code as it works for me. Best would be to edit the question

Comment: ya it is working mr.scoregraphic

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this may help.

```
^[0-9]{9}.
```

EDIT: Removed escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

`^\d{9}[A-Za-z]$`

To match 9 digits and one alphabetic character, and nothing before or after.

Comment: ya it is working tahnk u mr.ledhund

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex r = new Regex("[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]$");
label1.Text = r.IsMatch(textBox1.Text).ToString();
```

If specific character then:

```
[0-9]{9}v$
```